# How to deal with a column that has varchar values as well as large numbers that show up as scientific format?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena, scientific-notation

I'm loading data from csv files into tables in AWS Athena. There is a string column that has varchar values such `ABC123123` and really large numbers like `2588000000` (shows up in scientific format 2.588E+10) on parsing the csv and I want to convert only the scientific format to float so it shows up at `2588000000` and not with the scientific format.
I tried the following:

`SELECT ..., cast(column2 as float) FROM "db"."table"`

But I obviously cant CAST as float since there are varchar values in the same column.

I also tried the following:

```
SELECT column1, 
(CASE 
        WHEN column2 like '%E-%' THEN CAST(column2 AS FLOAT))
        WHEN column2 like '%E+%' THEN CAST(column2 AS FLOAT))
        ELSE column2
END)

FROM "db"."table"
```

And Athena gave this error [image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`try`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try):

```
SELECT coalesce(try(cast(cast(col AS doub) AS varchar)), col)
FROM ...
```

However, at least in current Presto, the double numbers end up cast to `varchar` with scientific notation, so you may need to go through `decimal`:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(
    try(
      cast(cast(cast(col AS double) AS decimal(38,19)) AS varchar)),
      col)
FROM ...
```

Comment: Hmm, that failed with the following error: `All COALESCE operands must be the same type: real`

Comment: Hmm, although when I'm verifying my data it seems like the numbers have changed. Printing the original column next to the updated one: original: `21268026375948` vs new after casting `21268025835520.0000...`

Comment: @bourgeoisna Replace `real` with `double`  in the casts (answer updated).
The numbers are too long to be represented in `real` (32-bit floating point) without loss.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . You need for the `case` expression to return a string.  So, format the float value as a string:

```
SELECT column1, 
       (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column2, '^[0-9]+E[+-]?[0-9]+$')
             THEN FORMAT('%f', CAST(column2 AS FLOAT))
             ELSE column2
        END)
FROM "db"."table"
```

Comment: When I tried above it showed "Unknown type: float" so I replaced `AS FLOAT` with `AS DOUBLE` then it gives the error: `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:14: Function format not regitered`